# Repress scientific notation from cut_number factor level names

Tags: r, ggplot2

How do I force ggplot2's cut_number function to not use scientific notation in the factor level names it creates? Instead of naming a bucket `(1.32e+03,2.89e+03]`, I would like it to simply be `(1320,2890]`.

Some code:

`x = rnorm(1000)*1000
x = x%/%1
df = data.frame(x=x)
df$g <- cut_number(x,10)`

This gives me factor level names like `(1.32e+03,2.89e+03]`.

Comment: @MrFlick added a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `dig.lab`, setting it higher than the default of 3.  See the documentation for `cut` for an description.

```
 cut_number(x, 10, dig.lab = 4)

[-4222,-1400]
```